# Passing array via module in verilog

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, verilog, system-verilog

I have a module named dct_8p where I have an input array of 8 elements, where each element is a 4 bit number and 8 element output array each contains 5 bit number. I want to pass each 4bit number input through the module.

I was trying to read the design through design vision. It generates an error:

> /Farhana/Synopsys/dct_8p.v:56: Illegal reference to memory xin. (VER-253)

I guess I am doing very silly mistakes in array declaration which I cannot get.

```
module dct_8p(xin,cin,add,sub,xout);
input [3:0] xin [0:7]; 
input cin; 
output [4:0] xout[0:7]; 
input add,sub; 



//layer 1 
RCA3 #(.n(4), .approx(0)) l10(.p(xin[0]),.q(xin[]),.ci(cin),.op(add),.r(xout[0]));
.... 
.. 

module RCA3(p,q,ci,op,r); 
parameter n=4; 
input[n-1:0]p,q; 
input ci,op; 
output [n:0] r; 
parameter approx=0;
....
....
```

Comment: 2 dimensional arrays ports are not supported in Verilog; make sure you have SystemVerilog enabled. It is recommended that SystemVerilog files use the `.sv` instread of the `.v`.

Comment: check that you have an index for the second `xin`?

Comment: I have tried .sv extension but still i am obtaining same error. I want to pass 4 bit register value in test bench script but l10 does to receive the input.

Comment: can anyone please provide an example?

Comment: Try passing -sverilog to vcs compile time switch. (This is for SystemVerilog)

Comment: `.q(xin[])` looks odd. Do you mean `.q(xin)` or `.q(xin[0:7])`?

Comment: that was a writing mistake. it would be xin[7]. In the main code it was alright.

Answer (score 3):

I compiled your code [here](http://www.edaplayground.com/x/NnD) and it worked perfectly. I've used xin[7] as input, as you informed.

SystemVerilog allows passing Multi Dimensional arrays as input to modules. You can modify the sample code and verify that fact.

The command for execution of SystemVerilog code using synopsis-vcs is as follows:

**vcs -timescale=1ns/1ns +vcs+flush+all +warn=all -sverilog -R**